# What Mail Transfer Agents is PHP using?

Tags: centos, email, php, mail-transport-agent

I'm trying to diagnose a problem with certain email addresses possibly being blocked on my server. I'm running PHP 5.3 on CentOS 5.7. The php.ini file lists a sendmail_path of `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`, which when run in CLI hangs there. I've noticed that qmail is installed on my server, too, but I don't know if PHP is using it or not.

How do I find out which MTAs (i.e. sendmail, qmail, etc) PHP is using?

Comment: Just make sure you look at the correct php.ini and you'll get your answer.  There's no other way.  That said, your description of your actual problem is confusing.  Perhaps you should focus on the real problem.

Comment: *Every* proper unix MTA installs a binary called `/usr/sbin/sendmail` which will respond to all common `sendmail` flags and commands. This is something people agreed to do specifically so that all POSIX software that isn't an MTA of itself will never need to worry about which MTA is installed.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I believe it is the right php.ini file. I checked `<? phpinfo() ?>` for the right path. What do you think the real problem is?

Comment: @Shadur so sendmail is just a generic binary run by qmail?

Comment: Unless you or your distribution did something *spectacularly* ill-advised, almost certainly yes.

Comment: Troubleshooting email delivery is a complex task and you don't specify what is actually happening.  Are some people receiving it while others don't?  Can you reproduce that error with one of your own email address?  From my experience, giving advice on troubleshooting email is a long term approach whereas knowing the actual situation with the SMTP server address and the domain name can allow someone experienced to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: PHP doesn't *care* about what MTA you're using.**

Longer explanation: this goes way back almost as far as the POSIX standards themselves, but *every* properly written MTA will provide a binary named `sendmail` that will behave *exactly* as the "official" `sendmail` program would be expected to behave.

As a result, *every* unix program or daemon that, for one reason or other, finds itself needing to email someone, knows they can just call `/usr/sbin/sendmail` with known options, and be confident that whatever MTA was installed will know what to do with the message from there on in.

As such, unless you use a specific SMTP PHP module and explicitly to use different mail settings (generally, a remote server/port with or without TLS and/or authentication), it will just call `/usr/sbin/sendmail` and let the underlying distribution worry about what happens next.

If your mail isn't arriving, I recommend you check the error logs of the MTA (usually in `/var/log/mail.*` but depends on your distribution and MTA) for answers.

Comment: I didn't find `sendmail` under `/usr/sbin/`.

Comment: Look under `/usr/bin/` then.

Comment: Doesn't exist there either.